# Access the current request from Karate

Tags: karate

I'm seeking guidance on accessing the request object from a JavaScript function in order to update the headers, and generate an AWS Signature V4.

To generate an AWS Signature V4, you need to access the existing headers (accept, content-type, host), and the actual request body as those are necessary to calculate the signature.

I have reviewed the `configuration headers`, but I am uncertain how to access the current request, or if only the body and headers are necessary.